# Texture based on tag in MC Java 1.19.2

Tags: java, json, minecraft

I'm trying to make a texture pack that changes a crossbow's texture based on a specific tag for ex.
If a crossbow tag is "Cool_Crossbow" then it uses cool_crossbow.png

This is how I set the crossbows tag:

```
ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.CROSSBOW);
ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
NamespacedKey key = new NamespacedKey(hex, "One_Punch_Bow");
meta.getPersistentDataContainer().set(key, PersistentDataType.STRING, "One Punch Bow");
```

I did some digging on how to set a texture based on a tag and this is what I came up with:

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/my_custom_crossbow_model"
    },
    "overrides": [

        {
            "predicate": {
                "tag": {
                    "One_Punch_Bow": "One Punch Bow"
                }
            },
            "model": "item/my_custom_crossbow_model"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work (not surprised tbh). What is wrong here idk. Also please tell me if this even is the correct way to do this

Answer (score 1):

There is no predicate **tag** base on this [wiki page](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Models#Item_predicates)

You can use **custom_model_data**

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/my_custom_crossbow_model"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "predicate": {
                 "custom_model_data": INTEGER
            },
            "model": "item/my_custom_crossbow_model"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then you can set custom model data with this

```
ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
meta.setCustomModelData(INTEGER)
```

Also I recommend to search for help at this site https://www.spigotmc.org/